# AWS Glue wrong timestamp value. Is possible to change this datetype?

Tags: aws-glue

I have a parquet file with a few timestamp fields like:

```
    [{
        "dms_execution_ts": "2020-01-28 18:52:32.927790",
        "updated_at": "2020-01-09T14:40:29.944307Z",
        "call_completed_at": "2020-01-14T19:51:45.000Z"
    }]
```

The problem is that my schema from table and partitions are marking this field as timestamp and I'm getting strange values like `+51993-03-21 05:54:09.964`.

How can I make those fields be a simple string or a bigint?

Comment: I assume, you query this data with AWS Athena? If so, could you provide table definition, i.e. `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, please?

Comment: post your Glue script here